# Volatility: AutoMagic Symbol Table error

Tags: python, pdf, plugins, volatility, malware-analysis

I am trying to analyze the .vmem file from HoneyNet challenge 3: Banking Troubles ([HoneyNet](https://www.honeynet.org/challenge-3-of-the-forensic-challenge-2010-banking-troubles/)) using **volatility3.** But I can't seem to get past this error:

```
PS C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\HoneyNet\volatility3> python vol.py -f C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\HoneyNet\Bob.vmem -vv windows.pslist.PsList
Volatility 3 Framework 2.0.0
INFO     volatility3.cli: Volatility plugins path: ['C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\HoneyNet\\volatility3\\volatility3\\plugins', 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\HoneyNet\\volatility3\\volatility3\\framework\\plugins']
INFO     volatility3.cli: Volatility symbols path: ['C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\HoneyNet\\volatility3\\volatility3\\symbols', 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\HoneyNet\\volatility3\\volatility3\\framework\\symbols']
INFO     volatility3.framework.automagic: Detected a windows category plugin
INFO     volatility3.framework.automagic: Running automagic: ConstructionMagic
INFO     volatility3.framework.automagic: Running automagic: LayerStacker
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.automagic.windows: Detecting Self-referential pointer for recent windows
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.automagic.windows: Older windows fixed location self-referential pointers
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.automagic.windows: DtbSelfRefPae test succeeded at 0x319000
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.automagic.windows: DTB was found at: 0x319000
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.automagic.stacker: Stacked layers: ['IntelLayer', 'FileLayer']
INFO     volatility3.framework.automagic: Running automagic: WinSwapLayers
INFO     volatility3.framework.automagic: Running automagic: KernelPDBScanner
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.automagic.pdbscan: Kernel base determination - searching layer module list structure
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.automagic.pdbscan: Setting kernel_virtual_offset to 0x804d7000
DEBUG    volatility3.framework.symbols.windows.pdbutil: Using symbol library: ntkrnlpa.pdb\BD8F451F3E754ED8A34B50560CEB08E3-1
INFO     volatility3.framework.automagic: Running automagic: KernelModule
WARNING  volatility3.framework.plugins: Automagic exception occurred: ValueError: Symbol type not in symbol_table_name1 SymbolTable: _ETHREAD

Unsatisfied requirement plugins.PsList.kernel: Windows kernel
Unable to validate the plugin requirements: ['plugins.PsList.kernel']
```

I have already downloaded and updated the windows symbol table, from [here.](https://downloads.volatilityfoundation.org/volatility3/symbols/windows.zip)

The .vmem file is  downloaded from [github.](https://github.com/markofu/pcaps/blob/master/HoneyNet/0310/hn_forensics.tgz)

Can anyone give me any sort of clue on how to proceed or anything new I could try?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, re-replacing the symbols at volatility3/symbols solved my issue.

Downloaded the symbols file from the above link, extracted it, copied and pasted the resultant windows folder at volatility3/symbols.

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue for some reason.